# Check if current page is the homepage

Tags: templating

I'm trying to run a check within my `_layout.html' to remove the navigation bar if the user is on the homepage. I've tried with the following code below, but browsing to a page which is the`index.html` of a Channel breaks the code with the following error:

> Variable "entry" does not exist.

This is the code within my `_layout.html`

```
{% set handle = entry.section.handle %}
{% if handle == 'homepage' %}
{% else %}
  {% if not craft.app.user.isGuest %}
      {% set users = craft.users %}
      {% include '_navigation'%}
    {% else %}
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works in Craft 3

```
{% set url = craft.app.request.url %}

{% if url == "/" %}
   homepage
{% endif %}
```

Comment: It doesn't work if the user comes to the page via something like Facebook, which would add a `/?fbclid=XXXXX` parameter to the end of the URL

Comment: I've gone with:

`{% if not craft.app.request.segments|length %}`

Answer (score 9):

Our `homepage` is set via [Craft's recommendation](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/entries.html#entry-uri-formats):

> You can designate any one entry as a site’s homepage using a special **home** URI.

Since the `homepage` is an entry, it will always have an `entry` object with a [uri](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-base-elementtrait.html#uri), so I can use a simple one-liner like:

`{% set isHomepage = entry is defined and entry.uri == "__home__" ? true : false %}`

Answer (score 7):

I'd rather:

```
{% if entry.uri == "__home__" %}
  
{% endif %}
```

Comment: this only works if the page is pulling from an entry, otherwise: Variable "entry" does not exist.

Comment: @LeoLeoncio The homepage is an entry, so if you are checking if whatever you're on is the homepage or not, you can assume false if there's no entry object. Otherwise, it's a custom setup and answering would require more info.

Answer (score 7):

The best option for Craft 3 and 4 is probably [`entry.isHomepage`](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-base-element.html#ishomepage), i.e.

```
{% if entry is defined and entry.isHomepage %}
   This is the homepage
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

To prevent a Twig exception, you may wish to use `entry is defined` to catch this error.

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tests/defined.html

Another way to detect the homepage would be looking at the request with `craft.app.request`, something like `craft.app.request.pathInfo`, if it equals `/`, then you've got your condition.

Answer (score 2):

Another option for you. Check for the presence of a url segment.

```
{% if not craft.app.request.segment(1) %}
    This is the homepage
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

This works nicely and limits error possiblities:

```
{% if craft.app.urlManager.matchedElement and craft.app.urlManager.matchedElement.uri == '__home__' %}
    Show on homepage
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

My site is localized, so I ended up doing...

```
{% if craft.app.request.url == '/' or craft.app.request.url == '/' ~ craft.app.language %}
```

Answer (score 1):

My current approach

```
{% if entry.isHomepage|default %}
Homepage
{% endif %}
```

Tested in Craft4